# Vue doesn't render a simple text on local server

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Just start to learn Vue following the official guide, but stuck in a problem that looks stupid. I want to render a pure text, but I can't find where I was wrong.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    <div id="comparison">
        comparison
    </div>

    <script src="../static/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It could be rendered well here, but it doesn't appear in my HTML page on local server by Flask.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8RRh.png)

Even I can access the data by Vue extension.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5RY4.png)

Comment: It could be about delimiters. Try to upload your local code here so we can see more details about it.

Comment: @mulsun Sorry but this is already the local code, may be I misunderstand something? And what do you mean "about delimiters"? it's about the braces or anything else?

Comment: Correct, for instance see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838135/vue-app-doesnt-load-when-served-through-python-flask-server

Comment: Yes it is! I ignored the jinja template also use braces. Thanks!